# RemoveAll from map in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, immutable-collections

**C#:**

In C# I have something like this:

```
IImmutableDictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"K1", "V1"},
    {"K2", "V2"},
    {"K3", "V3"},
}.ToImmutableDictionary();

IEnumerable<string> keys = new[] {"K1,K3"};

map = map.RemoveRange(keys);
```

I assume that the method [`ImmutableDictionary<K,V>.RemoveRange Method (IEnumerable<K>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn455939(v=vs.111).aspx) was introduced since it is much more efficient than series of `Remove(K)`calls. It creates the resulting immutable object only once instead of once for every element from `keys` to remove.

**F#:**

What is the best way to achieve the same in **F#**. I came up with this recursive solution:

```
let rec removeAll (map:Map<string, string>,  keys:list<string>) =
    match keys with
        | [] -> map
        | _ -> removeAll(map.Remove(keys |> Seq.head), keys.Tail)
```

but I doubt it is as efficient as the `RemoveRange` from above.

**Questions:**

1. What is the most efficient equivalent of `RemoveAll` in F#?
2. Do you think F# recursion optimization is going to compile to something equally efficient?

Comment: Any reason not to use `RemoveRange` as in c#?

Comment: As I know F# `Map<K,V>` has no `RemoveRange`, that's why in this case I have to convert to `ImmutabelDictionary<K,V>` forth and back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map.filter` will be useful here and will presumably prevent creating many intermediate maps, though to use it efficiently for many keys you'll want to put the keys into a set first.

```
let removeAll keys map =
    let keySet = set keys
    map |> Map.filter (fun k _ -> k |> keySet.Contains |> not)

[ 1, 2
  3, 4
  5, 6
  7, 8 ]
|> Map
|> removeAll [1; 5]
// map [(3, 4); (7, 8)]
```

This is small enough that it's potentially not worth breaking out into a function. For example in a case where you have an array of no more than 10 keys, then it may be less efficient to make a set out of them first.

Your current function is tail-recursive so it should be optimised in terms of not creating multiple stack frames, however you can write it a bit more simply by using pattern matching on the list:

```
let rec removeAll (map:Map<_,_>,  keys:list<_>) =
    match keys with
        | [] -> map
        | key :: rest -> removeAll(map.Remove(key), rest)
```

Also note that it can automatically be made generic by either removing type annotations or replacing parts of them with `_`, telling the compiler to infer the type.

Comment: The filter solution is a good one, although I wonder if the recursive one will still create intermediate maps.

Comment: Yes the recursive solution will create intermediate maps. However, they will probably use structural sharing like any good functional immutable data structure. That means that they won't be fully copied with each iteration, but I would still guess it would be slower than using `Map.filter`. That is a guess though!